# Require or Import default from ES6 on node

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I am working on a test suite and I came across this dilemma:

*Importing ES6 js from a file with require or with import?*

I am currently using mocha and chai for testing, with babel already configured.

Now I came up with a solution but I believe it is not "good practice", in fact after some trial and mainly one error stating that `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getUsers'` I found that if I:

```
export default Utils;
```

where Utils is an object, and inside my (ES5) test suite I

```
var util = require('./../src/utils/Utils');
```

it triggers the mentioned error. Same if I try the ES6 version:

```
import Utils, * as util from './../src/utils/Utils';
```

While if I

```
import Utils from './../src/utils/Utils';
var util = Utils;
```

it works, can someone explain me why is that?

I probably need to specify that util get used by calling one of the functions defined inside the Util object exported, like: `util.functionName();`

Comment: Have you tried to look at what's imported? `util` should be an object with named exports and `default` property for default export, `Utils` should be default export. [`import ..., * as ...` is there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults) exactly to cover this case.

Comment: I feel bad for not having logged it before, thanks for the inputs guys. It is indeed a duplicate of that question. At least I know why now. feel free to remove this question!